# Avg_Row_length not showing any result

Tags: php

I am trying to get the Avg_Row_length in PHP but when i echo the result it shows nothing. I tried to debug the issue but no logs were created.

My Query:

```
$avg_length_row = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Avg_Row_length FROM 'information_schema.tables' WHERE table_name = 'assignment'");
echo "AVG LENGTH " . (string)$avg_length_row . "<br>";
```

Comment: Try `var_dump($avg_length_row)` to see what result you actually got.

Comment: @IMSoP Here is the result: bool(false)

Comment: Aha. Now look up [the manual page for `mysqli_query`](http://php.net/mysqli_query), and look at what it returns: "Returns FALSE on failure." So from there, you can look up how to [find the last error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). Note also that the result of `mysqli_query` will *never* be something that you can use as a string, so even without the error, your code would not have worked.

Comment: One more debugging tip: get phpMyAdmin, or some other MySQL query UI, and paste in the SQL you are trying to run. If it doesn't run there, it won't run in PHP either.

Comment: The query is working perfectly.

I tried changing it to mysql_query 
$avg_length_row = mysql_query("SELECT Avg_Row_length FROM 'information_schema.tables' WHERE table_name = 'assignment'");

And on using var_dump i am getting resource(2) of type (mysql result)

Comment: Then perhaps you have not connected to the database successfully (i.e. `$con` is not initialised correctly).

Comment: It is connected as other queries are working fine.

Comment: Well, have you checked the error message, as I posted in my comment?

Comment: Ok what i found now is that after running the query in phpMyAdmin i am getting the result but also it is saying that "Showing rows 0 - 0 ( 1 total, Query took 0.0011 sec)".

This is weird.